# Redirect to some URL as per keyword match (htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I wanted to redirect person coming to:

```
http://website.com/index.php/m-p OR any other page after m-p/<any>
```

to:

```
http://website.com/index.php/cs
```

Help me!

Answer (score 1):

Solved myself. I am not sure if this is fully correct OR is supposed to be done this way, but it fulfilled my requirements-

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/m-p$ http://website.com/index.php/cs [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/m-p/(.*)$ http://website.com/index.php/cs [R,L]
```

Experts may guide.

Thanks